# How to put photos between text files string.xml (android book)

Tags: xml, string, text, between, photos

How to put photos between text files `string.xml` on `android book`.
This is my string.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">mybookname</string>
    <string name="num_of_tuts">53</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="Titlez">

    <item>test1</item>
    <item>test2</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Coontextz">
     <item>aaaaabbbbbbcccccccccdddddddd</item>
        <item>aaaaaaabbbbbbbcccccdddddddd</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```